# banshee can't write to my Drobo FS SMB shares

Tags: permissions, smb, drobo, drobo-fs

My Drobo FS has a few shares. I mount them on my Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit machine with no problem and can write and read those shares. When I run Banshee (2.2.1) in order to rip CDs into my Drobo, it fails with permission error when trying to create the directory.

When looking at the Banshee process it runs with my credentials (`ps | grep banshee`) so what am I missing?

Comment: tried to add the tag "drobo-fs" but cant due to low reputation. Who/Where do I suggest this tag to?

Comment: I added it for you – it seems reasonable enough that someone would use it in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found out what I was missing... mount point was mounted as root - didn't use the uid, gid options... and I could create files only from Windows...

so for the next puzzled guy here's what you need to put in your fstab file:

```
//your-server-name/path /your-mount-point    cifs   username=serveruser,password=serverpassword,_netdev,uid=clientuser,gid=clientgroup     0       0
```

Hope this helps someone...